# Proxy pass with host in headers causes loop redirects

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

**Use case**

We need to redirect to current website (ip1 - https://host.com/path) from a new server (ip2) that will host another website under root path (https://host2.com/). In the end, this last website will be hosted as https://host.com/, meaning that we will have one website on https://host.com/ (hosted on ip2) and another one on https://host.com/path (that is hosted on ip1)

NGINX is running on ip2 server.

Current website only accepts requests from host.com

**Current config**

This is what we are trying to do right now on ip2 server

```
location /path/ {
  proxy_pass https://ip1/path;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host host.com;
}
```

If we try to access https://host2.com/path, the config is working well.
When we change the DNS to set ip2 as host.com and then if we try to access https://host.com/path, NGINX is processing the request but then we have infinite 302 redirections to https://host.com/path (until browser eventually stops the process)

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I *think* you need to balance your slashes, `location /path/ ` needs to match with `proxy_pass  https://ip1/path/ ;` also with a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

We finally found a configuration to handle this issue :

```
location /path/ {
  proxy_pass https://ip1/path/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host host.com;
}
```

Watch out to the protocol (https) and the trailing slash character.

We moved the DNS to redirect host.com to ip2 and it's working like a charm !

Comment: This `proxy_pass https://<domain>;` doesn't work... if you're using an ssl config you proxy to http. Please don't post questions and then misleading answers to your own questions on the web. It pollutes the comment section for everyone else...